# python - how to check if string contains whitespaces around it

Tags: python, django

How can I know if

```
word = " a "
```

has a whitespace around it (which it does here, but word is dynamic) and then, iff it does, then `strip()` it?

Comment: What's wrong with just calling `word.strip()` every time?

Comment: Is every string going to look like this? If so I would suggest just strip() on every string without even bothering to check

Comment: Does it matter to you that it has white-spaces or not? Because if it doesn't matter and you just want to remove white-spaces, you can just use `strip()`; no matter how it is!

Answer (score 4):

There is no point in checking before stripping. Just use `str.strip()`; it is safe to do so if there is no whitespace around the text:

```
word.strip()
```

If you really need to test, you could use [`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and [`str.endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) with tuples:

```
whitespace = tuple(' \n\r\t')
word.startswith(whitespace) or word.endswith(whitespace)
```

is true if there is whitespace at the start or end.

Answer (score -1):

That may sound pretty silly, but as you're talking about *only one space*, why not do like this:

```
>>> a=" a "
>>> a[0]==' ' and a[-1]==' '
True
```

And then

```
if a and a[0]==' ' and a[-1]==' ':
    #do the stuff you want to do
```

Comment: you should also check if it's not empty

Answer (score -1):

Can you not just `strip()` all words, will you not get the same result?

Answer (score -1):

Compare the length before and after?

```
word = " a "
stripped = word.strip()
if len(word) != len(stripped):
    return stripped
else:
    return word
```

Answer (score -1):

I would look into the `startswith` and `endswith` methods:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_endswith.htm

```
if word.startswith(' ') and word.endswith(' ') then
    ...
```